# Avoiding nested Subscriptions. Subscribe once a different subscription is ready?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Let's assume that my Angular 14 app has a `FireService` that will fetch the latest information for an object when the application loads. A page on the application must wait for the [Observable](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable) on the `FireService` to be ready before it can do whatever it needs to. This is what I'm currently doing, and I'm sure is wrong:

##### fire.service.ts

```
export class FireService {
  public thingA$ = new BehaviorSubject<ThingA | undefined>(undefined);
}
```

##### page.component.ts

```
this.FireService.thingA$.subscribe((a: ThingA | undefined) {
  if (a) {
    this.thingB$.subscribe((b: ThingB) => doThingWithB(b));
  }
});
```

Would I use a [skipWhile](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/skipWhile) like this?

```
this.FireService.thingA$.pipe(skipWhile((a: ThingA | undefined) => !a)).subscribe((a: ThingA) {
  if (a) {
    this.thingB$.subscribe((b: ThingB) => doThingWithB(b));
  }
});
```

Wouldn't this also be a *nested subscription*?

Comment: Are you using the value of the `thingA$` subscription or are you only waiting for it to emit? In both cases `switchMap` would be an operator to get rid of the nested subscriptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are several things that you can do that will improve your code a lot.

You had the right idea and were on the right path.

you can use the helper functions `filter` to filter the emissions that you don't like, and `concatMap` to concatenate the first emission to the second emission.

You can also use `skipWhile` but in this case I think filter is more *descriptive*, but feel free to leave the other one.

```
this.FireService.thingA$.pipe(
  filter((a: ThingA | undefined) => a != null),
  concatMap(() => this.thingB$),
).subscribe({
  // note that this notation is preferred in latest rxjs versions
  next: (b: thingB) => doThingsWithB(b),
  error: (e) => handleTheError(e),
});
```

Also, you need to add `takeUntil` so this BehaviorSubject closes before component destroy (otherwise you get memory leaks).

So you would end up with something like:

```
// on top of the component
private this.destroy$ = new AsyncSubject<null>();

// where you sub to this:
this.FireService.thingA$.pipe(
  filter((a: ThingA | undefined) => a != null),
  concatMap(() => this.thingB$),
  takeUntil(this.destroy$)
).subscribe({
  // note that this notation is preferred in latest rxjs versions
  next: (b: thingB) => doThingsWithB(b),
  error: (e) => handleTheError(e),
});

// now adding on destroy
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destory$.complete(); // this triggers the takeUntil
}
```

**Ignorable suggestions:**

There are more improvements I'd suggest to you. The first one, is removing logic from the `subscribe` method and leaving that empty. There are two *operators* that can do this (I prefer the second option):

`tap` let's you create side effects without affecting the outcome, while
`map` allows you to modify what the `subscribe` method will get.

So, if your `doThingsWithB` function is a side effect, you can call it with tap and it would look like this:

```
this.FireService.thingA$.pipe(
  filter((a: ThingA | undefined) => a != null),
  concatMap((a: ThingA) => this.thingB$),
  tap((b: ThingB) => doThingsWithB(b)),
).subscribe();
```

which is more readable. Can also allow you to leave this observable in a variable, and call the `subscribe` later.

Also, if you usually use the data that comes from the observable, like assigning it to a value that is passed to the template, you can map it and use async pipe. So instead of

```
thingB = undefined;
this.thingB$.subscribe(b => thingB = makeCalculationWithB(b.prop));

<div>{{ thingB }}</div>
```

You can just map it, and use the async pipe.

```
thingB = this.thingB$.pipe(map(b => makeCalculationWithB(b));

<div>{{ thingB | async }}</div>
```

which would handle the unsubscribe as well, which is an added bonus (no need to `takeUntil` or `ngOnDestroy`). Also allows for easier extension of the logic in the future, becase you just add the pipes to it.

Comment: This is great, thank you! How would I use the value from `thingA$` in the `tap`?

Comment: just pass it the same way. `(tap(a: ThingA) => doSomethingWithA(a))` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call them in parallel, and thingB is not dependent on thingA result, then:

```
forkJoin(
    this.FireService.thingA$(),
    this.FireService.thingB$()
).subscribe(
    ([thisngA, thingB]) => {
        // do your things
    },
    (error) => console.error(error)
)
```